# Android Studio или Unity для AR приложения?

Tags: android, unity3d, android-studio, ar

Хочу написать AR приложение для Android. Знаю, что там и там создовать AR приложения возможно, но все таки, где это будет делать удобнее? Какая платформа более гибче? Какой сложности можно создавать приложения на каждой из платформ? Хотелось бы получить советы от опытных людей! Я склоняюсь больше к Unity, но опыт разработки есть только на AS.

Comment: AS - не платформа.

Comment: `ИЛИ` работает только с чем-то равным. А вы путаете `тёплое` с `мягким`. AS это DevKit.